# Adding attributes as a dropdown in Main Category Navigation

Tags: attributes, navigation, menu

I'm working on a site that has main categories and there are product attributes that appear in the layered nav such as brand, type, color.

I would like to have a dropdown when hovering on a category link in the main nav that would have links for some attributes under that category

For example the categories are "Men's Shoes" "women's shoes" and under each one would be links for "by color: white, brown, etc." by occasion: casual, dress, etc."

How would go about creating something like this?

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7329/146) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3157799/2047249). I've put up the following "module" that should do what you need.
The main idea is to get the categories menu, identify the attributes used in layered navigation and display a link to the filtered category for each option in the attribute.
The extension is called `Easylife_Nav`. The extension files:

**`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Nav.xml`** - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Nav>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Nav>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**`app/code/local/Easylife/Nav/etc/config.xml`** - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Nav>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Nav>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <easylife_nav>
                <class>Easylife_Nav_Helper</class>
            </easylife_nav>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <easylife_nav>
                <class>Easylife_Nav_Model</class>
            </easylife_nav>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before> <!-- observe the menu generation event -->
                <observers>
                    <easylife_nav>
                        <class>easylife_nav/observer</class>
                        <method>addAttributes</method>
                    </easylife_nav>
                </observers>
            </page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**`app/code/local/Easylife/Nav/Helper/Data.php`** - the module main helper

```
<?php
class Easylife_Nav_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

}
```

**`app/code/local/Easylife/Nav/Model/Observer.php`** - the module observer

```
<?php
class Easylife_Nav_Model_Observer {
    public function addAttributes($observer){
        $menu = $observer->getMenu();
        $tree = $menu->getTree();
        //get all first level menu items
        foreach ($menu->getChildren() as $child){
            $nodeId = $child->getId();
            //check if the node id starts with `category-node-` - so it's a category
            if (substr($nodeId, 0, strlen('category-node-')) == 'category-node-') {
                //identify the category id
                $id = str_replace('category-node-', '', $nodeId);
                //remember the main category url
                $mainUrl = $child->getUrl();
                //get category filtrable attributes
                $attributes = $this->getAttributes($id);
                foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 
                    //get the options for each attribute
                    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
                    if (count($options) > 0) {
                        //add "By ..." menu item - non clickable
                        $attrNodeId = 'attribute-'.$id.'-'.$attribute->getId();
                        $data = array(
                            'name' => Mage::helper('easylife_nav')->__('By %s', $attribute->getFrontendLabel()),
                            'id' => $attrNodeId,
                            'url' => '#',
                            'is_active' => false
                        );
                        $attrNode = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
                        //for each option add a new sub menu
                        foreach ($options as $option) {
                            if ($option['value']) {
                                $optionNodeId = 'attribute-'.$id.'-'.$attribute->getId().'-'.$option['value'];
                                $data = array(
                                    'name' => $option['label'],
                                    'id' => $optionNodeId,
                                    'url' => $mainUrl.'?'.$attribute->getAttributeCode().'='.$option['value'],
                                    'is_active' => false
                                );
                                $optionNode = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
                                $attrNode->addChild($optionNode);
                            }
                        }
                        $child->addChild($attrNode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //get allowed attributes in that category
    public function getAttributes($categoryId) {
        $layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
        $layer->setCurrentCategory(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId));
        $validAttributes = array();
        foreach ($layer->getFilterableAttributes() as $attribute) {
            //allow only select attributes - you can implement your additional filters here
            if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'select'){
                $validAttributes[] = $attribute;
            }
        }
        return $validAttributes;
    }
}
```

Clear the cache and try it out.

Comment: Can we  do it same for attribute type:Mulitple select.
what i want is to display all values of specific attribute and when one of the value is selected , all categories who has that value selected should be displayed

Comment: @Vishal I'm not sure I understand you question, but to clear your thoughts, here is what the script above does. It gets all the filtrable attributes from a category with the type 'select' (you can change it to support multiselects also) and adds them to the main menu, with a link to that category but with the filter applied. So you will only see the products from the selected category and with the filter applied by an attribute value. Is that what you need?

Comment: Here the attributes that you are saying is related to products right?

Comment: @Vishal. Yep. They are all the product attributes that appear in the filters when looking at a category page.

Comment: instead of product attribute ,my question is for Category attribute. Is it possible? I create a ** `custom CATEGORY attribute` ** and then use that attribute in nav.

Comment: @Vishal. I don't know. I don't even understand how you can use that in the attribute nav? Where should the link point to?

Comment: ::i am explaining the exact scenario: WE have football tshirt (final product to sell) This tshirt is associated with some player Called B. Now player B is a part of different club say club A,Club B,Club C. Now in top menu i want to include different Club Names. So when user select Club A , all players under club A will be displayed and when any particular player is selected ,all products associated with that players will be shown

Comment: @Marius can you help me out in http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50115/adding-product-filterable-attributes-to-the-category-navigation