# how can I add a link to my navigation menu

Tags: menu, toplinks

I'm wondering the best way to add a custom link to the top navigation menu?

[image]

Comment: give this a try http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7329/146

Answer (score 0):

Depends how flexible you would want it.  You can modify the block/phtml template in:

> app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml

New unordered list items can then be added there.

It is also possible to add a static block there that will give CMS Adminstrators the ability to add custom links.  This is handy if deployments to Production environments involve some extra planning or scheduling.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I looked for app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml but can't seem to find it. I get to app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/template/catalog/ but the only folder in there is "product". I turned on my developer mode to try and see if that would show me the path and this is what I saw: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QvmmC.png (see above edit) does that mean it is in header.html?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow bellow two link.

[Adding Page Links to the Main Menu](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar)

[Adding links to top menu in magento](http://sohelrana09.wordpress.com/2014/03/03/adding-links-to-top-menu-in-magento/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I had this one working http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar but it kept resetting itself or something. I'm not sure what is happened. It worked 2 days ago and was redirecting to store.com/sale and not all of a sudden it's redirecting to sale.html