# Is there a way of adding a link to a Product Page to Top Navigation?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, navigation, toplinks

I'm very new to Magento, so this might be VERY basic...

I've read about adding links to CMS pages in the Navigation Bar
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar

Is there a simple way of adding a link to a Product Page?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Magento Ce-1.7 the top menu does not consist of only categories.
You don't need to edit templates to add a new menu item.
There is this event you can observe: `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before`.
You receive as a parameter to the observer the current menu.
You can see in this question [Adding links to category menu](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7329/146) how to add something to the top menu.
The question is for something related, but you should find what you need in the question itself.

Comment: I looked at the question - but I didn't understand any of it!

Comment: @PhilStewart. Maybe you should get familiarized first with the [Event-Observers](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) magento offers. Then the question should be more clear.

Comment: Thanks @Marius - but the link doesn't work :(

Comment: @PhilStewart. It's because of the damn markup SE uses and because the url has underscores in it. Just Google `magento event observer` and the first link from `magentocommerce.com` that shows up, is what you need.