# Add CMS page links into Nav menu using local.xml

Tags: xml, navigation, toplinks, layout

I have been trying to add cms page links into the Main navigation using the local.xml file. I tried the following, however this references the top links instead of the main nav.

```
<reference name="top.menu">

        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>test</label>
            <url>/</url>
            <title>test</title><prepare>true</prepare>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>5</position>
        </action>

</reference>
```

I would like the main menu to go:
Home   |    Products (with drop down)   | CMS Page | CMS Page | CMS Page | etc.

Is this possible through xml?

Thank you

Comment: You can add anything to the topmenu using the event `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before`. [See this as example](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7329/146) the example is in the question, not the answer

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. They quickest way to go about this is probably adding it by including a static block next to the header (or use a custom menu extension).