# Varien_Data_Tree_Node - Position nav menu items

Tags: navigation, rwd, varien

Digging into the 1.9 RWD nav menu, I am fiddling with `Varien_Data_Tree` and `Varien_Data_Tree_Node` - I haven't worked with these classes directly before and they seem unfinished as there are several empty methods in the classes.

Using an observer on the `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` event, I am able to add a new item to the menu using:

```
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $menu = $event->getMenu();
    $nodeData = array(
        'name'      => 'My Node',
        'id'        => 'my_node',
        'url'       => 'My-Url.html',
        'is_active' => false
        );
    $node = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($nodeData, 'my-node', new Varien_Data_Tree());
    $menu->addChild($node);
```

As expected, I see a new nav menu item on the front-end listed after any other nav items already built; however, I would like to position this node so that it is shown before or after any other items (such as how `before="-"` `after="-"` are used in layout XML).

**How can I adjust the position of items added to the nav menu in this fashion?**

Answer (score 3):

Marius to the rescue! Its not an elegant solution but seems to be the only approach. Since its a matter of getting the existing tree items, temporarily storing the data, removing them and then readding the existing items with the newly inserted one before.

Taken from: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7361/69

```
public function addItemsToTopmenuItems($observer){
    //get the menu object -Type Varien_Data_Tree_Node
    $menu = $observer->getMenu();
    //get the tree object in the menu -type Varien_Data_Tree
    $tree = $menu->getTree();
    //get current page handler
    $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
    $brandNodeId = 'category-node-brand';
    //set the node id, label and url
    $data = array(
        'name' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Brands'),
        'id' => $brandNodeId,
        'url' => Mage::getUrl('brands'),
        'is_active' => ($action == 'brands')
    );
    //create a node object
    $brandNode = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
    //temporary array with nodes
    $menuItems = array();
    //my first menu item
    $menuItems[] = $brandNode;
    //loop through existing menu items, add them to the array and remove them from the    menu
    foreach ($menu->getChildren() as $child){
        //add the item to the temp array
        $menuItems[] = $child;
        //remove item from the menu
        $menu->removeChild($child);
        //I need to add a new menu item after the category with id 6
        //don't worry the id is not hard coded. it comes from a config setting
        //I just added 6 here to make it easier to read
        if ($child->getId() == 'category-node-6'){
            //create a new node as $brandNode called $newNode
            ...
            //add the node to my temp array
            $menuItems[] = $newNode;
        }
    }
    //add other nodes at the end of my temp array
    ...
    //recreate the menu in the order I need
    foreach ($menuItems as $child){
        $menu->addChild($child);
    }
}
```

Also it may be worth mentioning that Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection implements [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).

Comment: Don't know how I missed that question. This is pretty much what I was suspecting I would need to do.

Comment: I feel like there might be a better solution if a simple `sort_order` is added to each node and then rearrange the menu's array inside the `topmenu/renderer.phtml` template based on `sort_order`.

Comment: May offer a better elogant solution: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/Data/Tree/Dbp.php#L281

Comment: @B00MER. The `move` method you linked works for tree behavior with links to the database. It would be nice to have such a method for non-db related trees.