# How to add custom page's navigation in the top main navbar?

Tags: navigation

I also want to include home button at the first position of top main navigation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to edit the template `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml` and add a `li` element with a link to the homepage.

So this:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <?php echo $_menu ?>
</ul>
```

becomes this:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="home"><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('')?>"><?php echo $this->__('Home')?></a></li>
    <?php echo $_menu ?>
</ul>
```

But this means it will be available only for your current theme.
If you want it to be available independent of the theme you can use the `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before`.
And example on how to use that can be found here: [Adding links to category menu](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7329/146)