# Topmenu - hide and display certain categories

Tags: magento2, menu, topmenu

After reading the following post [Magento 2: How can I add External URL in top menu](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97120/magento-2-how-can-i-add-external-url-in-top-menu/116970#)

I was hoping to do something similiar .

We have a category attribute and want to display categories depending on a users logged in state. I was hoping that each of the children elements would have a canShow() function or similiar but it doesn't seem the case.

I don't really want to wrap around or replace the _getHtml function, but I don't see clean way of doing it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have a potential solution.
I'm going to do a afterGetChildren()

inside that function i'm going to loop through the children and delete them from the tree based upon the attribute.