# Magento 2 - Adding a CMS page link to menu

Tags: magento2, navigation

Although this sounds really straight forward I can't work it out. All the existing methods seem to be for Magento 1.x

I would like to have all my CMS pages in the top menu.

Comment: You can read more here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/adding-a-non-category-link-to-the-navigation-links-in-magento-2/96076

Comment: i think you have to create an own NAV module for it. Load all cms page url's instead of the categories.

Answer (score 3):

I've done it in the following way without any changes in the code:

1. Content from the page (PageA) is put in a new block (BlockA).
2. I make a new category with only content and without products (CategoryA)
3. In the Content section: Add CMS Block -> Add BlockA
4. Change layout if needed and save.

That's it!

In case you still need PageA just delete content from it and add CMS Block (BlockA) as a widget.

Comment: How do you do step one "put in a new block (BlockA) while the block is created in step .3?

Answer (score 2):

Without any extension,it's not possible.

### But there is an alternative

Basically, we use ***cms page*** for ***cms content management***.

As per my knowledge, there is a process in ***category system*** where you can manage **cms content**.

Just create ***a cms static block***   and assign that `static block` to the category from ***Display setting tab***.

Then,set ***Display Mode*** as ***Static block only***. Do not assign any products to that category.

### If you don't want an alternative then you have to create custom module

Free extension available at [Github](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento2-add-cms-pages-to-menu)

Or build the module yourself as per below steps:

Then  create plugin for class `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu` and
and use `before` plugin on **getHtml()**

**First,** create a module.

**Second:** *create `di.xml` where we will define plugin*.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="add_cms_menu" type="{VendorName}{ModuleName}\Plugin\Topmenu" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Third**: Now create the plugin class where we will add a cms page link to the menu.

and also in this way **we can add a cms page link** at navigation.

> app\code{VendorName}{ModuleName}\Plugin\Topmenu.php

```
<?php 
namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
class Topmenu
{
    protected $nodeFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }
    public function beforeGetHtml(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject,
        $outermostClass = '',
        $childrenWrapClass = '',
        $limit = 0
    ) {
        /* Showing  Cms page About us at menu */
        $page = $this->getCmspage('about-us');
        if($page == null){
            return;
        }


        $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'name' => $page->getTitle(),
                    'id' => $page->getIdentifier(),
                    'url' =>  $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(null, ['_direct' => $page->getIdentifier()]),
                    'has_active' => false,
                    'is_active' => false // (expression to determine if menu item is selected or not)
                ],
                'idField' => 'id',
                'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree()
            ]
        );
        $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
    }
    protected function getCmspage($identifier){

        $page = $this->_pageFactory->create();
        $pageId = $page->checkIdentifier($identifier, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());

        if (!$pageId) {
            return null;
        }
        $page->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        if (!$page->load($pageId)) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!$page->getId()) {
            return null;
        }

        return $page;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a static block with a list of your pages, then add it to your <Magento>/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/etc/default.xml file.

The CMS block would look something like:

```
<li class="level0 level-top"><a class="level-top ui-corner-all" href="{{store direct_url="about-us"}}">About Us</a></li>
<li class="level0 level-top"><a class="level-top ui-corner-all" href="{{store direct_url="contact-us"}}">Contact Us</a></li>
```

And the code in default.xml would be placed within the  block:

```
<body>
...
<referenceContainer name="catalog.topnav">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="your_block_id">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">your_block_id</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
...
</body>
```

Additional styling may be needed, but with the blank theme using the classes level0 and level-top in your CMS block should match up.

Answer (score 1):

*self promotion*

We made an OpenSource Module where you can link a category to a specific CMS page. So you have to create a Category for each CMS page and adjust the link via the module. In case you want to do it yourself, just have a look at the module :-)

https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect

Comment: After executing the composer command, im asked username and password. Is this my magento connect account?

Comment: I think the github account

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the **top.links** or the main navigation that's populated by categories?

Cause if you want page links in **top.links (header.links for Luma)**, then just create the page and add to **default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="header.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="about-us" before="-">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">About Us</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">about-us</argument>
    </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

That should link to your static pages.

Comment: yeah, at the moment it just display's categories. I want it to display, CMS pages, and the initial 'shop' page. Using your solution above, would I have to add each page in manually?

..sorry I'm completely new to Magento!

Comment: My solution will only apply to the top navigation (the one right at the top of the page where the login/account links are) and all you would have to do is copy and paste the arguments with the page details you want to add. I'm sorry, I have no idea how to add to the categories nav.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin for the `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu` block's **getHtml** method and use it to iterate through the CMS pages, inserting the links into the html.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you have Magento Enterprise Edition, you can use the Hierarchy feature.  That's precisely what it's intended to allow you to do (among other things).

Comment: Hierarchy affects the sidebar, not the main menu out of the box; http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/cms/page-hierarchy.html

Comment: Sorry, but that's just not true. If the docs claim it, theyre incorrect. I use this feature all the time.  There's a specific setting for using top navigation as opposed to on page (which is, of course, there, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Want to add a link to the top navigation within `<header>`
Adding a link to CMS page, Gallery

Edit/Place default.xml here:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

Add the following code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="catalog.topnav">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="gallery.link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Gallery</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">gallery</argument>
                </arguments>
          </block> 
       </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This adds a link to CMS page, Gallery, with the following settings:

```
Title = Gallery
Url Key = gallery
Link = https://example.com/gallery/
```

Add the following styling to ensure the new link aligns correctly:

```
.navigation .nav.item {
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}
```

[image: Results of the code]
(Products is setup as a category for an example)