# add CMS page link category menu in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, navigation

How to add cms page link category navigation menu Like

Example Like Home | About Us | Contact Us | Our Products

Please check screenshot

[image]

Comment: You can check this answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/adding-a-non-category-link-to-the-navigation-links-in-magento-2. Good luck

Comment: have you tried this link? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/adding-a-non-category-link-to-the-navigation-links-in-magento-2

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123669/magento-2-adding-a-cms-page-link-to-menu

Answer (score 1):

**Another alternative** is to use a new template file via layout xml.

> ./app/design/frontend/Company/Yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright info.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
            <block name="custom.menu.links" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu_custom.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then use this template file to create link html.

> ./app/design/frontend/Company/Yourtheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu_custom.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
?>
<li class="level0 level-top ui-menu-item">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."faq"; ?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all"  role="menuitem">
        <span><?= __("FAQ")?></span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="level0 level-top ui-menu-item">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('custom/index/index'); ?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all"  role="menuitem">
        <span><?= __("Custom Designs")?></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

When you clear the layout and block_html caches, these will show in the menu. 
Note:

- This way we won't touch the original `topmenu.phtml`
- This will use topmenu.phtml's `$block->getChildHtml()` to render the output
- In layout xmls if you ignore the `class=""` attribute for a block, then `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class will be used by default.

Hope that helps