# How to add Contact Us in the Top menu?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add Contact us Menu into the top navigation menu but its not Working for me.

I am trying using default Contact Us page but its not showing in Top Menu.
      From admin panel I was Enable yes Contact Us. But When Go to the Block section I don't get the Contact Us Page.

I need to add that contact us menu side to the About us top menu?

How can achieve this?

[image]

Comment: It would be really helpful if you get a bit common with markdown, and format your questions according to this: https://markdown.de/

Comment: Simply I want add Contact Us page from footer into the Top Menu bar?

Comment: Use this extension: https://github.com/devamitbera/magento2-add-cms-pages-to-menu
For more detail visit this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123669/magento-2-adding-a-cms-page-link-to-menu

Comment: Its not working for me. any other solution? Plz help

Comment: I have Contact Us page in the footer? I want that Contact Us page in Main menu

Answer (score 0):

There's a Mega Menu extension from weltpixel which lets you include custom links in the menu. I believe you just have to create a category and set the link for it, and you can link your Contact Page there