# Adding External Link To Magento 2.1 Topbar / Navigation

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, navigation

I Have Followed Follwing Article [From Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96076/37321) For Adding External Link To Magento Navigation Also Referred [Magento 2 Repo.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/078af98a52912fbae0142577ae4da422bb6705dd) And Created The Plugin.  But Its Not Adding Link To My Navigation Bar.

Answer (score 0):

Please create the plugin using the following steps:

**Module's di.xml**

```
 <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
    <plugin name="modulename-topmenu" type="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Topmenu\Plugin" />
 </type>
```

**Plugin Class**

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Topmenu;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;

    class Plugin
    {

        protected $nodeFactory;
        protected $urlInterface;

        public function __construct(
            NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface
        ) {
            $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
            $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        }

        public function beforeGetHtml(
            \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject,
            $outermostClass = '',
            $childrenWrapClass = '',
            $limit = 0
        ) {
            $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
                [
                    'data' => $this->getNodeAsArray(),
                    'idField' => 'id',
                    'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree()
                ]
            );
            $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
        }

        protected function getNodeAsArray()
        {
            return [
                'name' => __('Anchor name'),
                'id' => 'anchor-id',
                'url' => $this->urlInterface->getUrl('url-key/'),
                'has_active' => false,
                'is_active' => false 
            ];
        }
    }
```