# Magento 2: put all CMS pages in the top bar

Tags: layered-navigation, navigation, magento-2.1.7, cms-pages, topmenu

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

By default, it seems, Magento displays links to the *product categories* (and subcategories) in the *top bar*. I need to display *only* the CMS (static) pages there.

The code from *default.xml* that displays the top bar is:

```
<container name="navbar-collapse" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="collapse navbar-collapse" htmlId="wg-navbar-collapse">
  <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-">
     <arguments>
       <argument name="parent_item_class" xsi:type="string">dropdown</argument>
       <argument name="submenu_class" xsi:type="string">dropdown-menu</argument>
     </arguments>
  </block>
</container>
```

Replacing `catalog.topnav` with `cms.topnav` did not produce any change in the frontend. I could not find a way to do that through the admin either.

How must I do it?

Alternatively, is there a *free plugin* for this functionality?

Thank you!

Comment: This will require you to create a custom module or buy an extension, since this functionality is not part of Magento core

Comment: Where can I copy one from? Magento is _really new_ to me.

Comment: You will need to develop one from scratch or buy an extension, It's a long process creating this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a plugin in your custom module to achieve this. 
Have a look at this answer to add your cms-page/custom-link in top menu.

[Adding a non-category link to the navigation links in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96076)

Comment: Is there a _free plugin_ for this functionality?

Comment: It's a custom plugin. You can create your own plugin using above link. If you are creating your own custom plugin then it is absolutely free :)