# How to add custom link in main menu in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, topmenu, link, submenu

I want to add **CMS pages** and **Contact page** link in the main menu.

How to add these links in the main menu and their submenu as well?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/adding-a-non-category-link-to-the-navigation-links-in-magento-2/360510#360510

Answer (score 12, accepted):

copy file from

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml
```

and put this file in your theme location

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml
```

Add below `<li>` structure just after `<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>` line in topmenu.phtml

```
<li class="level0 level-top ui-menu-item">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."yourlink"; ?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all"  role="menuitem">
        <span><?php echo __("Your Custom Menu")?></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Could you please add a way to make the link visibility on Mobile vs Desktop controllable. E.g. only show the link on Mobile.

Comment: I would do it using CSS/LESS. Better to do it in the client-side than server-side as the pages should be responsive.

Answer (score 12):

**Another alternative** is to use a new template file via layout xml.

> ./app/design/frontend/Company/Yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright info.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
            <block name="custom.menu.links" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu_custom.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then use this template file to create link html.

> ./app/design/frontend/Company/Yourtheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu_custom.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
?>
<li class="level0 level-top ui-menu-item">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."faq"; ?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all"  role="menuitem">
        <span><?= __("FAQ")?></span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="level0 level-top ui-menu-item">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('custom/index/index'); ?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all"  role="menuitem">
        <span><?= __("Custom Designs")?></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

When you clear the layout and block_html caches, these will show in the menu. 
Note:

- This way we won't touch the original `topmenu.phtml`
- This will use topmenu.phtml's `$block->getChildHtml()` to render the output
- In layout xmls if you ignore the `class=""` attribute for a block, then `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class will be used by default.

Hope that helps

Comment: With your alternative method, could you please add a way to make the link visibility on Mobile vs Desktop controllable. E.g. only show the link on Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Extend default.xml layout file in your current theme to create new defaul.xml at path - ./app/design/frontend/Company/Yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
                    <block 
 class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="custom- 
 top-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" 
 xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Top Link</argument>
                            <argument name="path" 
 xsi:type="string">*/*/*</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </referenceBlock>
            </body>
```