# Add Custom Link In Main Menu Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.3.5

I need to add Custom Link In Main Menu Only apply **Specific Text**. currently i have display  menu as category. i want to add **link** only **where to buy** menu. please help me & Suggest how can i add menu?

Please See my **attached** files. [image]

**Thanks In Advance**

Comment: please check this answer, maybe it's help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206572/how-to-add-custom-link-in-main-menu-in-magento-2

Comment: @FaisalSheikh thanks for reply, but this method is add in last menu, not work in middle menu

Comment: is last 4 link are custom links?

Comment: @AmitBera (our story,faq,our chaitable work) menus are static block, but where to buy is page link.

Answer (score 1):

If the last 4 links are custom links, then you can those custom links add this using Plugin.

> See:
>   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Create a plugin on class Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu as the menu is rendered from this class and use before plugin on `getHtml()`.

The menu is rendered from this class and use before plugin on `getHtml()`.

**1.  create a module.module should have minimum below files:**

```
app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/module.xml
app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/composer.json
app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/registration.php
```

**2: create di.xml where we will define the plugin.**

location: `app\code{VendorName}{ModuleName}\etc\frontend\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="add_cms_menu" type="{VendorName}{ModuleName}\Plugin\Topmenu" sortOrder="20" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**3. Now create the plugin class where we will add a cms page link to the menu.**

```
public function __construct(
    NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
) {
    $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
}
public function beforeGetHtml(
    \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject,
    $outermostClass = '',
    $childrenWrapClass = '',
    $limit = 0
) {
    /* Showing  Cms page About us at menu */
    $page = $this->getCmspage('about-us');
    if($page == null){
        return;
    }


    $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
        [
            'data' => [
                'name' => $page->getTitle(),
                'id' => $page->getIdentifier(),
                'url' =>  $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(null, ['_direct' => $page->getIdentifier()]),
                'has_active' => false,
                'is_active' => false // (expression to determine if menu item is selected or not)
            ],
            'idField' => 'id',
            'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree()
        ]
    );
    $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
}
protected function getCmspage($identifier){

    $page = $this->_pageFactory->create();
    $pageId = $page->checkIdentifier($identifier, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());

    if (!$pageId) {
        return null;
    }
    $page->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    if (!$page->load($pageId)) {
        return null;
    }

    if (!$page->getId()) {
        return null;
    }

    return $page;
}
```

}

More detail can found [article](https://www.amitbera.com/magento2-add-a-cms-page-link-to-menu/)

Answer (score -1):

copy file from

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml
```

and put this file in your theme location

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml
```

Add below `<li>` structure just after `<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>` line in topmenu.phtml

```
<li class="level0 level-top ui-menu-item">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."yourlink"; ?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all"  role="menuitem">
        <span><?php echo __("Your Custom Menu")?></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

And more read link :-

**[How to add custom link in main menu in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206572/how-to-add-custom-link-in-main-menu-in-magento-2)**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Hey Mohit thanks for reply, but this method is add in last menu, not work in middle menu.

Comment: I am no sure but try  first line add update line `<li class="level0 nav-3 level-top ui-menu-item">`