# Menu item using observer

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

How we can create a menu item using Observer in **Magento version 2.2.0.**
Please help me on this.

Comment: Kindly elaborate your question

Comment: I need to add new item in mega menu using observer

Comment: Please refer this link:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212347/magento-2-add-link-with-content-to-top-menu/212369#212369
This seems similar to your question.