# Add a custom navbar menu

Tags: magento2.3, navigation, topmenu

I am trying to add a custom link(contact us) in navbar menu and wanted to add the contact us page link.
how to add that?

Comment: please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/adding-a-non-category-link-to-the-navigation-links-in-magento-2 and https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-link-in-navigation-menu-in-magento2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the below code in theme **default.xml** file

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="custom.contact.link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact us</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">contact</argument>
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">custom-contact-link</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Not working Sir.
I am using Magento 2.3.0. And the theme is the Porto theme.

Comment: @ChandanSayed , Porto theme has the option to add menu item before and after the main menu, Please check in Megamenu Configurations. there is an option to assign block from after menu.

Comment: <body>
                <move element="sw.topnav" destination="store.menu" before="-"/>
        </body>

Comment: So you mean to apply my code you need to add <move element="sw.topnav" destination="store.menu" before="-"/> , Right?

Comment: app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Megamenu
default.xml

<body>
        <move element="sw.topnav" destination="store.menu" before="-"/>
    </body>

Comment: sir, I share the code from default.xml

Comment: Okay, but how you added contact us link to top menu?

Comment: I tried to add but it is not working, Sir

Comment: app/code/Smartwave/Megamenu/view/frontend/layout
detault.xml
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Smartwave\Megamenu\Block\Topmenu" name="sw.topnav" template="Smartwave_Megamenu::topmenu.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="category_list_on_left" template="Smartwave_Megamenu::onepagecategory/category_list.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>

Comment: Check this default.xml too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102239/discussion-between-kishor-thummar-and-chandan-sayed).

Comment: app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Megamenu default.xml
<referenceBlock name="page.top">
        <block class="Smartwave\Megamenu\Block\Topmenu" name="custom.contact.link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact us</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">contact</argument>
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">custom-contact-link</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>

Comment: I tried to add the code you gave me

Answer (score 1):

Add Custom Header Links

Step 1: Create a layout XML file in the below path for add custom header.
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body> 
        <referenceBlock name="header.links"> 
            <move element="custom-link" destination="header.links"/> 
            <block class="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Header" name="custom-link" after="my-account-link"/>
        </referenceBlock> 
    </body> 
</page>
```

Step 2: Create a block file in the below path that is referred in the layout file.
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Block/Header.php

```
<?php 
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block; 
class Header extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link 
{ 
    protected $_template = ‘VendorName_ModuleName::link.phtml'; 

    public function getHref() { 
        return__( 'contactus'); 
    } 

    public function getLabel() { 
        return __('Contact Us'); 
    } 
} ?>
```

Step 3: Create a template file in the below path that is referred to the block file.
app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/link.phtml

```
<li> 
    <a <?php echo $block->getLinkAttributes() ?>><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel())?></a>
</li>
```

Add Custom Footer Links:

Step 1: Create a layout XML file in the below path for add custom footer.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body> 
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custom-link-2">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Footer Link</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">custom_footer_link</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body> 
</page>
```