# using javascript:void(0) to replace category link

Tags: category, menu

I want a menu item in main menu which the hyperlink is # or javascript:void(0), instead of by default it will show the category products, any method i can do that?

Comment: can you share your magento version or add tag in magento ver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some customization using magento event/observer.

The ***page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before***  event lets us add new links in the menu, to  `#` or `javascript:void(0)` or anything else.

#### Observer code

```
<?php 
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer {
    public function addItemsToTopmenuItems($observer) {
        $menu = $observer->getMenu();
        $tree = $menu->getTree();
        $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();

        $nodeId = 'some-node-id';
        $data = array(
            'name' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Title goes here'),
            'id' => $nodeId,
            'url' => '#', // any URL for the href attribute
        );
        $node = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
        $menu->addChild($node);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

#### config.xml code

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
            <observers>
                <[module]>
                    <class>[module]/observer</class>
                    <method>addItemsToTopmenuItems</method>
                </[module]>
            </observers>
        </page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

See more details at [Adding links to category menu](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7329/adding-links-to-category-menu)