# How to add outside link to the menu (categories)?

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, submenu

I want to add an external link in my menu (categories) that points to my blog. It's like that:

- My blog: blog.mysite.com
- My store: mysite.com

How to do that please?

Comment: There are many how-to's available on the internet. Did you take a look at them already before posting your question? I.e. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7329/adding-links-to-category-menu or https://ranasohel.me/2014/03/03/adding-links-to-top-menu-in-magento/

Comment: Have you done some research?  There is a simple one found here in an old stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911070/how-to-add-external-link-to-top-menu-item-in-magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You just have to lacate the phtml of your Menu and add your link, you can use [path hints](http://support.magerewards.com/article/1534-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints) to find the path phtml menu.
2. You can add your link simply like this:

   ```
   <li class="menu-class">
       <a href="<?php echo 'your link' ?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('My blog')?></span></a>
   </li>
   ```

   **NB:** some themes gives the possibility to add links in theme admin config.